# OpenTK - Useability of Accumulation Buffer

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, opengl-compat, accumulate

I'm trying to use accumulation buffer in OpenTK project to no avail.

I learned that in newer version of OpenGL it was removed so I was wondering if its usable in OpenTK and if yes then is it dependent on:

1. Libary im using - im currently using `OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL`.
2. The version of OpenGL set in shaders for example:

```c
#version 330

in vec3 vPosition;
in  vec3 vColor;
out vec4 color;
uniform mat4 modelview;

void
main()
{
    gl_Position = modelview * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);

    color = vec4( vColor, 1.0);
}
```

If any of this is at fault of not letting me use accum buffer then it will probably solve this question of mine too

[OpenTK - How to achive antialiasing using accumulation buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363130/opentk-how-to-achive-antialiasing-using-accumulation-buffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If deprecated functionality is still available, depends on the [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) type.

If you use a compatibility profile OpenGL Context, then all the deprecated functionality, as a accumulation buffer, is still available, even in the most resent OpenGL version 4.6.
In a core profile OpenGL context, the deprecated functionality is removed.

By default OpenTK creates a compatibility profile OpenGL context.